# Adding a SetTimeout and transition to jQuery Show / Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a `SetTimeout` and animation type transition to jQuery Show / Hide call. Below is how I currently have it but am wanting to add the a specific amount of time the 'show' div remains displayed before it reverts back to the orginal `#bg_dv`. I also want to add animated transitions between the effects if possible.

```
   function tilt(){
    $("#area1").click(function(){
        $("#bg_div").hide();
        $("#bg_skew").show(); // I would like to show this Div for about 5 seconds
 // and then have original back. 
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("#bg_div").hide(0).delay(5000).show(0);
$("#bg_skew").show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
```

If you want animations, you can replace the calls to `hide()` and `show()` with something appropriate. For example `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

Comment: I don't believe this works. Without arguments, `.show` or `.hide` are not animation methods, hence `.delay` does not have any effect on them.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've updated my answer to include a duration which turns them into animation methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $("#area1").click(function(){

        $("#bg_div").fadeOut('fast',function(){
             $("#bg_skew").delay(5000).fadeIn('fast');
        });


    });
```

In order to prevent caching of multiple clicks and have the animation play many times
you should also take a look at

```
.stop(true,true)
```

before any animation.Also take a look at this animation option - property.

```
{cache:false}
```

Answer (score 2):

it's so simple. just put milliseconds in `show.delay(5000)` it will delay it for 5 seconds.

syntax:

`$(selector).delay(speed)`

`speed`: time in millsecnds e.g. 5000 for 5 seconds.

`$(selector).show(speed,easing,callback)`

`speed`: here put time in milliseconds like 1000 for 1 second.

`easing`: it defins speed of elements at different points i.e.   "linear" "swing".

`callback`: here you can put your function it will execute after completing show method. For example when you will click button to show image after showing image it will exexcute funxtion e.g.     `.show(1000,function(){alert("hello")};);`

Hope i helped you.

Comment: It doesn't *delay* the execution. The *duration* of the animation will be 5 seconds.

Comment: ohh yes. sorry my mistake thanx